# symlink to PHP file not handled as PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, symlink, mod-alias

I have PHP5 installed on an Ubuntu 14.04 server and it works fine.  I create a file called foo.php anywhere in the document tree and it gets passed to the PHP interpreter just as you'd expect.

However... I don't want the .php extension to be visible in one particular case so I created a symbolic link using "ln -s foo.php foo".  If I go to http://localhost/path/to/foo.php then PHP works just fine, but when I go to http://localhost/path/to/foo then I see the PHP source.

I'm guessing that this is because the SetHandler directives in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf are in a `<FilesMatch>` directive and my filename doesn't end with ".php", but I've got FollowSymlinks enabled, so I was expecting that not to matter.  I guess it does.

I know I could use mod_rewrite to do an internal redirect, but that's a bit of a sledgehammer.  I could also use Redirect, but that pushes the redirection back to the client, which I want to avoid.

So is there an easy way to tell Apache "follow the symlink, then do auto-type determination based on the found file"?

Comment: If you're going to -1 a question, at least say why.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options it says

> Even though the server follows the symlink it does not change the pathname used to match against `<Directory>` sections.

I imagine the same is true for matching against `<Files>` sections, so it can't be done.  However, this comes close:-

```
<Location "/path/to/foo">
  SetHandler x-foo-handler
  Action x-foo-handler /path/to/foo.php virtual
</Location>
```